# Linux - Web Server creating restricted files

Tags: php, linux, apache

Whenever I create files (error log, for example) using PHP, the files are created under `www-data` ownership, this wouldn't be much of a problem but these files are created with the "Only Owner" write attribute, which prevent me from doing changes to them. (this becomes particulary annoying when I try to do Git changes or other clean up tasks).

The only way I can solve this is to removing them or change the ownership/permissions manually using `sudo`.

How can I set the default permissions/ownership to files created by PHP?

Comment: add your self to the www-data group

Comment: This worked nicely. Thank you.